# How to code watir to enter text in chrome

Tags: ruby, watir

I am trying to make an Instagram bot with a ruby file and watir gem. I need it to access the username and password text fields, but when I put in browser.text_field it won’t work. When the code reaches that line it closes the browser.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! But, "Where's the beef?". Please post some source code and check these guideline for best practises: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please add the (minimal amount of) HTML to reproduce the issue and/or provide a link to a test site.  Otherwise, it's just guessing...

Answer (score 0):

Write this code

```
require 'watir'
@b=Watir::Browser.new
@b.goto 'https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en'
@b.text_field(xpath: "//label[text()='Username']/following-sibling::input").set 'user'
@b.text_field(xpath: "//label[text()='Password']/following-sibling::input").set 'pass'
```